# Alternatives to piecewise

Tags: piecewise

As has been mentioned before, `Piecewise` causes the *Mathematica* Kernel to fail to during a `NDSolve` calculation. How can I write the function below without using `Piecewise`?

```
s[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, t < 300.}, {0, 300. <= t < 1500.}, {1, t <= 3600}}];
Plot[s[t], {t, 0., 4000.}]
```

Comment: More often than not `Piecewise` causes `NDSolve` to succeed in my experience.

Comment: I think Piecewise is the most straightforward method to use. But it is a little frustrating that he kernel crashes so often. Is there any precedent that the cause of the failures is related to the use of reals in the function definition for the independent variable t?

Comment: Yes, I think the use of approximate reals can make the analysis of the discontinuities computationally harder. Rounding error from transformations might slightly perturb quantities that ought to match up, for instance; `x^0.5` is very different from `x^(1/2)`, and so on. When someone here posts a problem with `NDSolve[sys,...]` and it seems related to this issue, I usually try it with `NDSolve[Rationalize[sys, 0],...]`, if nothing else seems more likely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the functions `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` and `` Simplify`SimplifyUnitStep `` to convert a `Piecewise` function to one using `UnitStep`:

```
s[t_] := Piecewise[{{1, t < 300.}, {0, 300. <= t < 1500.}, {1, t <= 3600}}];
s2[t_] := Simplify`SimplifyUnitStep[Simplify`PWToUnitStep[s@t]];
s2[t]
```

> 1 - UnitStep[-300. + t] + UnitStep[3600 - t, -1500. + t]

To use `HeavisideTheta` instead of `UnitStep`:

```
s2[t] /. UnitStep -> HeavisideTheta
```

> 1 - HeavisideTheta[-300. + t] + HeavisideTheta[3600 - t, -1500. + t]

```
Row[Plot[#, {t, 0., 4000.}, PlotStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {s[t], s2[t]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 @kglr, This is great. Is there a quick way to see other simplify subroutines in the Front-End?

Comment: @RashidZia, thanks for the vote. Perhaps ``?? Simplify`*``?

Comment: @ kglr, thanks again. I got it to work with ``?"Simplify`*"``  BTW there is also a ``Simplify`PWToHeavisideTheta`` function.

Comment: @RashidZia, I don't see a `PWToHeavisideTheta` function in Version 9.

Comment: I am using Version 10.4 and [this is what I see](http://imgur.com/zyDg8hn)

Comment: @RashidZia, that's great! Yet another reason to upgrade to v10:)  Maybe you can update your answer with that alternative.

Comment: @ kglr, unfortunately, ``Simplify`PWToHeavisideTheta`` doesn't seem to evaluate for this case, even if I play with the piecewise boundary inequalities. Perhaps some else knows how to use it....

Comment: I encountered an annoying issue with ```Simplify`PWToUnitStep```: if the original `Piecewise` expression has an `Indeterminate` branch (even at a single point), the whole result becomes `Indeterminate`. The workaround I use is to replace `Indeterminate` with `HeavisideTheta[0]` before calling ```Simplify`PWToUnitStep```.

Answer (score 6):

Two alternatives (depending on application) would be `UnitStep` and `HeavisideTheta`. For example,

```
sU[t_] := UnitStep[300 - t] + UnitStep[t - 1500, 3600 - t]
sH[t_] := HeavisideTheta[300 - t] + HeavisideTheta[t - 1500, 3600 - t]
```

For differential equations, I would use `HeavisideTheta`.